# Calling a function by adding an onclick event through innerHTML inside react class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, innerhtml

How to call a function by add an onclick event in react class through innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('activeEmployeesTableContent').innerHTML = `
                                    <tr>
                                      <td>${res.data.empId}</td>
                                      <td><button onclick = ${this.fun}>CLICK</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  `;
```

The above code is not working but i must use innerHTML to add the code dynamically into the table body

```
  componentDidMount(){
     axios.post('http://localhost:5000/employeesRetrieval')
      .then( res => {
          document.getElementById('activeEmployeesTableContent').innerHTML = `
                                  <tr>
                                    <td>${res.data.empId}</td>
                                    <td><button onclick = ${this.fun(res.data.empid)}>CLICK</button></td>
                                  </tr>`;
      }).catch( err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: This is intended as internal code in a custom element? I don't think this will work, as react is one big powerful engine for rendering client side components via transpiled javascript. Just because components (functional component, right?) looks HTMLish doesn't mean it is actually HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This seems tangential to React, however, you would typically add the onclick function separately from defining the `innerHTML`. I would recommend leaning into the DOM api if this is the route you're trying to go down.

```
const t = document.getElementById('table');
const row = document.createElement('tr');
const id = document.createElement('td');

// Set up the first element in the table
id.innerHTML = ele.empId;
row.appendChild(id);

// Set up the button
const btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.innerHTML = 'CLICK';
btn.addEventListener('click', func);
row.appendChild(btn);

// Add the row to the table.
table.appendChild(row);
```

This approach is overly imperative and generally lacking a framework so I wouldn't recommend doing something like this. Frameworks like React exist to help manage the complexity. React handles interactions with the DOM for you so you can focus on the business logic of your application.

Answer (score 0):

react is totally different thing, you cannot add react in plain html.